# Auto populate cell based on repeating formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2021

Cell B2 is (A2-A1). Cell B3 is (A3-A2).  Old versions would auto-populate the B cell as soon as I entered the A cell value, but with the newest version I can't seem to get it to  auto populate.  I'm stuck doing copy/paste over and over.   Seems like a simple fix that I just can't find.

Comment: Is the problem that the formula does not appear where you expect it to, or that the formula is there but does not re-calculate ehwn you enter or change the values in A1 A2 or A3? If it is the latter, it could be that calculation has switched to manual rather than automatic. Can you see the word "Calculate" at the bottom left corner of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select both cells B2 and B3 and click and hold the fill handle on B3 then sliding it down to where you want it. If there were adjacent cells then Excel will do it for you by double-clicking on the B3 fill handle.